# FastAPI, SQLModel - Pydantic not serializing datetime

Tags: python, fastapi, pydantic, sqlmodel

My understanding is that SQLModel uses pydantic BaseModel (checked the _mro_. Why is it that the bellow fails the type comparison. (err provided).

```
class SomeModel(SQLModel,table=True):
    timestamp: datetime
    id: UUID = Field(default_factory=lambda: str(uuid4()), primary_key=True)

def test_some_model():
    m=SomeModel(**{'timestamp':datetime.utcnow().isoformat()})
    assert type(m.timestamp)==datetime
```

**E       AssertionError: assert <class 'str'> == datetime**

FastAPI/SQLModel experts explain yourselves :D .

Note - I tried using Field with default factories etc... as well.

Comment: I'm not sure, but try changing `DateTime()` to `DateTime(timezone=True)`

Comment: Do you really need setting `created` and `modified` fields on client side? It would be better to set them always on SQL server side

Comment: @YuriiMotov this is more of a setup to get things working before porting things properly. These fields could be any other date field, im just testing things when a client sets different types if they get serialized correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding **validate_assignment** fixes the issue.

Picked this solution up from https://github.com/tiangolo/sqlmodel/issues/52 after more than a couple days of breaking my head. Hopefully this helps other poor souls.

```
   class SomeModel(SQLModel,table=True):
        class Config:
            validate_assignment = True
        timestamp: datetime
        age:int
        id: UUID = Field(default_factory=lambda: str(uuid4()), primary_key=True)
```